# Loop through self referenting list to add in treeview

Tags: c#, recursion, reference, treeview, self

I have a list like this

- ID | Name  | Title   | ManagerID
- 1  | Peter | CEO      | Null
- 2  | Eric  | Manager  | 1
- 3  | brad  | Economy  | 1
- 4  | Pit   | Sales    | 2
- 5  | Mike  | Secretary| 4
- 6  | Mac   | copier   | 5
- 7  | Ben   | Board    | Null

This list can be infinite. The null values in this are because they have no Manager.
How can I add this to a treeview and get all the parentnode and subnodes correctly?

Need to accomplish this in a loop, and cannot change the database where it comes from,
I want to do something like?

```
private void treew(TreeNode treeNode, List<Employees> employ)
    {
        foreach (Employees option in employ)
        {
            TreeNode nodeOutput;
    //Add parent node
            foreach (Employees optionItems in employ)
            {
                if (option.ID == optionItems.ManagerID)
                {
        //Add childnode
                    TreeNode nodeOption;
                    nodeOutput.Nodes.Add(nodeOption);
                }
            }
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(nodeOutput);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private List<Employees> employees;
private void treew(TreeNode root, int? managerID)
{
    foreach (Employees option in employ.Where(x => x.MangerID == managerID))
    {
        TreeNode nodeOutput;
        treew(nodeOutput, option.ID);
        root.Nodes.Add(nodeOutput);
    }
}
```

Either pass in the root node of your TreeView to the first call, or create another version which takes the TreeView as the first argument and does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: But how would i change the method to get this to be like a structured List<List< ?

Comment: @user1374734 - I'm not sure what you mean?